# Inject a row after X number of rows in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I display tables on a website with ±100 rows.

Is it possible to add a row after every 25 rows in order to display adcode?

Since new data are imported often from a csv file, I can't add these rows displaying the add at the same time.

This row will have to span across all columns. so I assume I can just add a very high number.

```
<tr><td colspan=100> DISPLAY ADD HERE </td></tr>
```

I'm using wordpress and ninja forms, though I don't think this will influence the way this is implemented. I just need to know is it possible with any plain HTMl table.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: The answer is "Yes it is" - I assume you meant "on the client"  - do you have jQuery or plain JS in mind?

Comment: Could you post a bit more code? I like to see how the rest of your table is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply iterate through table rows using a loop and add the row in between. Below is a code snippet,

```js
var i=0;
$('#table_name > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    i++;
    if (i%25==0) {
      $(this).after("<tr><td colspan=100> DISPLAY ADD HERE </td></tr>")
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems promising, but I think my issue is in implementing the Jaavscript. Here is my codepen; any advice? [link](https://codepen.io/schalkjoubert/pen/rQZLNO)

Comment: thank you so much, this works perfectly. And changing colspan from 100 to 0 make the columns span across all columns.

Comment: glad i could help :)